# What is ちゃんといた?

Tags: meaning

いた、いたちゃぁあんといたぁ！

Is it just ちゃんと and いた,
"it was perfect"?

It's from video game "Xenogears". Throne and Seraphita(villains) approach Fortress Jasper(where the heroes are) in their Gears(giant robots). First Throne, Seraphita right after her.

Seraphita says: 「トロネちゃん、トロネちゃん！！
　いた、いた  ちゃぁあんといたぁ！

Throne:「一回言やぁ、わかる。(answers to Seraphita) ふうん、ホントにやる気だったんだ。大型レーザの反射鏡攻擊なんておバカな事。(this part refers to the heroes' plan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いた is the perfect aspect of いる (to stay) here, which means to have stayed, in other words, "is there". (You use いる instead or ある when you refer to existence or presence of things that can essentially move themselves.)

ちゃんと is an adverb that basically means "properly" or "neatly", in this case it means how their target is there as is planed.

So it says "Throne, Throne, it's there, it's certainly there!".